# Infinity cyclic cover for knot complement

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, knot-theory

I was confronted with this phrase:

> Let $L$ be a link in $\mathbb{S}^3$ with complement $X$ and infinite cyclic cover $p:X_{\infty}\rightarrow X.$ Recall that $p_\ast :\pi_1(X_\infty)\to\pi_1(X)$ is an isomorphism onto the commutator subgroup $[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]$.

Now two question arised.

**Question 1.** Why does a knot complement has an infinity cyclic cover? (An infinity cyclic cover is nothing but a cover with fiber $\mathbb{Z}$, isn't it?)

**Question 2.** Why is $p_\ast (\pi_1(X_\infty))=[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]$?

EDIT: A construction for $X_\infty$ can be found 
[[here]](https://picload.org/view/rircicol/2017-05-18.png.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact that the abelianization of the knot group is $\mathbb Z$, so that the cover corresponding to the commutator subgroup is actually infinite cyclic.

Edit: Recall that the classification of covering spaces gives a bijection between subgroups of the fundamental group and covering spaces. So there is a cover corresponding to the commutator subgroup. This is a normal subgroup and so the group of deck transformations is $\pi_1(X)/[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]$. It is known that for knots this quotient (called the abelianization) is infinite cyclic. Thus you get a cyclic cover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this about question 1 or 2? I have little problems in understanding your answer, sorry.

Comment: It answers both questions.

Comment: @leparisien: I edited to give a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you! What I really wanted to know is why the Alexander-invariant $H_1(X_\infty)$ as $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$-module is equal for equivalent knots (links). I thought this would help because I alredy know that the knot group is an invariant. But $X$ is nothing but the knot complement which is also a knot invariant.How would you prove $H_1(X_\infty)$ being a knot invariant?

Comment: Well, $X_\infty$ can be constructed canonically from the knot complement. It's the cover that corresponds to the commutator subgroup. So the cover $X_\infty$ is isomorphic for equivalent knots.

Comment: Is this argument also right: Assume we have two equvalent knots, then their complements are the same (isomorphic). Since we have constructed $X_\infty$ out of the knot complement and these are equal this will lead to equal $X_\infty$ spaces. here I have not used something about the commutator.

Comment: The issue is you need to say *how* you construct $X_\infty$ from $X$, and that this construction only depends on the topology of $X$. This is why it's important to mention that it comes from the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group.

Comment: I have added a link to my question above where you can find the construction. The main question is, why does it come from the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: Basically because the generator of the abelianization is a meridian to the knot. So when you unwind the meridian, you get an infinite string of knot complements glued together. You could of course take the geometric construction as the definition of $X_\infty$, but then you would have to show it doesn't depend on the choice of seifert surface. However, that construction is indeed obviously isomorphic for isotopic knots.

Comment: Alright, so let's figure out why the construction of $X_\infty$ does not depend on any choices of a Seifert surface. In Lickorish's 'Introd. to knot theory' it is Theorem 7.9. It says: A loop $\alpha$ in $X$ lifts to a loop $\alpha '$ in $X_\infty$ iff $\alpha '(0)$ and $\alpha '(1)$ are in the same copy of $Y$. This is so iff $\alpha$ intersects $F$ zero times (for every time $\alpha$ crosses $F$, its lift moves from one copy of $Y$ to an adjecent copy. Thus $\alpha$ lifts to a loop iff $\text{lk}(\alpha,L)$ (sum of linking numbers of components) is 0. This is independent of $F$.

Comment: I do not understand this 3 equivalences.

Comment: Referring to a question in the comments: There is one detail about the $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$-module $H_1(X_\infty)$ being a knot invariant which is not just a matter of the cyclic cover being topologically unique, and that is the fact that the choice of generator for $H_1(X)$ ($t$ vs $t^{-1}$) gives an orientation for the meridian (equivalently, the choice of orientation of the Seifert surface).  It is a theorem that the "conjugate" module is isomorphic to the original module for knot complements.

Comment: @KyleMiller: that is true!